# Combination of students Block Design

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, sports-league-scheduling-problem

My classmates and I are preparing for a competition. I am in charge of dividing the 60 of them into teams of 6 . The teams members will be rotated every week . I would like to team them up in such a way that no two members from the same team go to another team during the next switch.
Googling and checking in stackover flow I found a certain question similar to this ( forgot to mark the URL :( ) . Based on the answers provided I came to the following conclusion :
Each and every person has to sit with 59 others . 
In every shift the person has to sit with 5 others .
so there are 59/5 ways I can make a person sit that satisfies my constraint . 
Since 59/5 is NOT an integer , it is impossible .

1. Am I Correct in assuming this ?
2. And will it be possible to achieve a solution using a technique such as backtracking ? If so can anyone tell me how one can achieve such a solution ?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: The answer is (60! / (6! * 5!)).  That's a rather large number.  I hope your class is a long one.

Comment: Is the ***only*** rule that no two people are on the same team with each other from `week = X` to `week = X+1`?  If so then this is easily doable.

Comment: @Eric J. can you tell me how you came to the solution  60! / (6! * 5!) ?

Comment: @RBarryYoung  . I was actually hoping to include the entire history of a person and not just from Week X to Week X+1

Comment: You should explain that constraint clearly in your post then.  And in that case, it depends very greatly on how many weeks you want to run this.

Comment: I want to run this for 16 weeks. Can you give me an idea on how to solve it just for the case  between week = x and week = x+1 ?

Comment: No,  I doubt that you can get more than 10 weeks using any simple incremental rule strategy.

Comment: In fact, you cannot get more than 11 weeks with any plan.  At the end of 11 weeks, every person will have shared a team with 55 other people, leaving only 4 other people.  Thus on the twelfth week they will have to repeat with someone on a team.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. No student on a given week will end up on the same team as any of their teammates from the previous week.

- Players from Team 0 goto: T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5
- Players from Team 1 goto: T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6
- Players from Team 2 goto: T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7
- Players from Team 3 goto: T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8
- Players from Team 4 goto: T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9
- Players from Team 5 goto: T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T0
- Players from Team 6 goto: T6, T7, T8, T9, T0, T1
- Players from Team 7 goto: T7, T8, T9, T0, T1, T2
- Players from Team 8 goto: T8, T9, T0, T1, T2, T3
- Players from Team 9 goto: T9, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4

Comment: This is correct for the original question as stated.  (one member of the team can stay in the same team without seeing any other members of that team).  It will be insufficient for the expanded/corrected constraint, however, because that requires a multi-week plan.